# Gibt es Minimalpaare unter ŋɡ, ŋ, nɡ, ŋk, nk?

Tags: pronunciation

Gibt es Minimalpaare unter ŋɡ, ŋ, nɡ, ŋk, nk? Am interessantesten wären natürlich welche unter den ersten drei bzw. letzten zwei, da diese jw. gleichgeschrieben werden.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Innerhalb eines Morphems ist /n/ schwierig, da /n/ vor /k/,/g/ dann zu /ŋ/ wird. Für die restlichen findet man offensichtlich z.B.

> Inga /iŋga/ und Inka /inka/ sowie Häng! /heŋ​/ und Henk! /heŋk/

Ein Minimalpaar von /ŋg/ und /ŋ/ innerhalb eines Phonems zu finden ist schwierig, da auf /ŋg/ fast immer gespannte und auf /ŋ/ fast nur ungespannte Laute folgen. Z.B.: "Singer pur" und "Singapur" unterscheiden sich auch in /ɐ/ vs. /​a/.

An Wortgrenzen gestaltet sich das einfacher. Für die Varianten mit *g*:

> bang gewirkt /baŋgəwirkt/, Bange wirkt /baŋəwirkt/ und Bann gewirkt /bangəwirkt/

Nur muss man hier einwenden, dass wenn man /ŋ/ generell /ŋg/ spräche, die ersten beiden theoretisch als /ŋg/ vs. /ŋgg/ mit längerem /g/ unterscheiden könnten.

Für /ŋk/ und /nk/:

> Bankkreis /baŋk(k)raɪ̯s/ oder (hypothetisch) Bank-reis /baŋkraɪ̯s/ und Bannkreis /bankraɪ̯s/

Comment: Gibt es irgendeine Region im deutschen Sprachraum, wo /ŋ/ generell als /ŋg/ gesprochen wird?

Comment: @Uwe Ich weiß es nicht, ich glaube, das schon einmal gehört zu haben, aber kann mich auch irren. Ich ändere es mal in Konj. II. Schließlich sind Minimalpaare auch für die Diagnose von Sprachfehlern zu gebrauchen.